# AngularJS array iterate object and compare strings inside it

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS project that aims to display our online store's name, location and operating hours on front end.

Sample expected result on front-end:

[image]

The JSON data structure looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "address": {
      "city": "Haarlem",
      "housenumber": "89",
      "streetname": "Zilweg-Oost",
      "zipcode": "2013 EG"
    },
    "pickupName": "Haarlem Pick-up Point 89",
    "operatingHours": {
      "Friday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Monday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Saturday": {
        "string": "10:00-21:00"
      },
      "Thursday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Tuesday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Wednesday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "address": {
      "city": "Haarlem",
      "housenumber": "19",
      "streetname": "Zilweg-Oost",
      "zipcode": "2013 AF"
    },
    "pickupName": "Gamma Ray Den Haarlem",
    "operatingHours": {
      "Friday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Monday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Saturday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Sunday": {
        "string": "13:00-17:00"
      },
      "Thursday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Tuesday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Wednesday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "address": {
      "city": "Haarlem",
      "housenumber": "183",
      "streetname": "Zilweg",
      "zipcode": "2015 BG"
    },
    "pickupName": "Uitvaartcentrum Omega Point",
    "operatingHours": {
      "Friday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Saturday": {
        "string": "10:00-17:00"
      },
       "Saturday": {
        "string": "12:00-17:00"
      },
      "Thursday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Tuesday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      },
      "Wednesday": {
        "string": "09:00-19:00"
      }
    }
  },
]
```

I tried fetching the `operatingHours` object and pushed it in a separate array.

Now my problem is how can I iterate, compare each strings and validate if Monday time is the same as for Saturday time, etc. and then display it on my page?

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to just compare the times of different days, you don't need to iterate as this is an object. Just reference the property object references you are comparing.

```
if(operatingHours.Monday.string === operatingHours.Saturday.string){
    //-- Do your stuff
}
```